# ADODB.Recordset vs ADO.Net

Tags: ado.net, adodb

I have migrates an application from VB6 to .Net 2005 and found ADODB.Recordset in that. Should I leave it as it is or should I change it with ADO.Net? Any insight about how ADODB.Recordset works in .Net environment will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I would leave it as it is if I did not have a compelling reason to update it. Leaving what is working saves a lot of time.